# Parsing JSON with GSON without knowing the value format

Tags: java, android, json, gson

hi guys i have a api like [this](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a176e8cf456f47749900fd7c5f9d9f55) you can see i have a metaData array and all of the items in the array have a Integer id and a string key but value is not the same in all of them i defined the value in the Object but i have an error this is the error

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3871 path $[0].meta_data
```

and this is my POJO class

Main Pojo(Product) class

```
@SerializedName("meta_data")
@Expose
private MetaDatum metaData;
```

and this is the MetaDatum Class

```
public class MetaDatum implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("key")
@Expose
private String key;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private Object value;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public Object getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Object value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeValue(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.key);
    dest.writeParcelable((Parcelable) this.value, flags);
}

public MetaDatum() {
}

protected MetaDatum(Parcel in) {
    this.id = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
    this.key = in.readString();
    this.value = in.readParcelable(Object.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<MetaDatum> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MetaDatum>() {
    @Override
    public MetaDatum createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new MetaDatum(source);
    }

    @Override
    public MetaDatum[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MetaDatum[size];
    }
};
}
```

Comment: add your url to call api and give json data after that i provide code.

Comment: pl give full link to give response in json data.

Comment: @AndroidTeam hi thanks a lot for the help this is the url i get the data from:https://goorab.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=ck_9d6e6c2de8e8934fe8a2a4030a94925874f72d17&consumer_secret=cs_2aa11efeea5a600cbe09f18698b2e92753830793

Answer (score 0):

Your meta_data is array instead of object

```
meta_data": [
      {
        "id": 3281,
        "key": "_vc_post_settings",
        "value": {
          "vc_grid_id": []
        }
      ]
```

So use List

```
private List<MetaDatum> metaData;
```

Answer (score 0):

make all pojo class for your json data using robopojo puligns or http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

after that make retrofit object define base url and other things...

```
public class ApiClient {
private final static String BASE_URL = "https://goorab.com/wp-json/wc/v2/";

public static ApiClient apiClient;
private Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new ApiClient();
    }
    return apiClient;
}

//private static Retrofit storeRetrofit = null;

public Retrofit getClient() {
    return getClient(null);
}


private Retrofit getClient(final Context context) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
}
```

and make interface for api calling..

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@GET("products")
Call<ResponseData> getdata(@Query("consumer_key") String key);
```

}

after that calling into activity or fragment like below.

```
ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getInstance().getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseData> responseCall = apiInterface.getdata("pass key");
    responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseData> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseData> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null && response != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GetData" + response.body().getLanguage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseData> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Errror", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

and make sure pojo class are all valid.

Comment: i tried this pojo generator site before for the same api and its not working i have the same error

Comment: used robopojo pulign for pojo class generate.

Answer (score 0):

All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped: quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F)

Comment: your Unicode text break the JSON format in data, so you must be used encoded JSON data

Comment: its encoded you can send the request :https://goorab.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=ck_9d6e6c2de8e8934fe8a2a4030a94925874f72d17&consumer_secret=cs_2aa11efeea5a600cbe09f18698b2e92753830793

Comment: yeah..i was seen that, name property content text need to be encoded

Comment: i don't have trouble with whole json file i can receive the file my problem is meta_data and i cant see the name on meta_data